# Update table view after delete core data in child view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uiviewcontroller

I need to update table view in MainView controller with UITableView, after deleting item in DetailView controller with button for delete, using core data.

Core data structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ0k8.png

In MainView controller i have a table with orders, press on order will open a detailview controller with food and order where I can delete the order. After that I need to `[self popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`;

Code for deleting object, where self.orderItem - order passed to DetailView controller:

```
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.orderItem];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
```

Comment: just call `[table reloadData]` before that reconstruct your `datasource`

Comment: im calling reloadData in viewDidAppear in MainView, but rows arent deleted they just empty

Comment: what have you written in `numberofrowsinsection` are u not returning `[datasource count]` ?

Comment: i have it, main problem is what im deleting object in child controller and i need to update main controller

Comment: added as answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should recreate `nsfetchrequest` and refetch data from coredata in `viewWillAppear` and once your `datasource` is updated call `[table reloadData]`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use a NSFetchedResultsController. It will act on changes to the data it is fetching and you can update the table. This is an excellent tutorial. http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Answer (score 1):

write code inside viewWillAppear of mainviewController 
 for reload table view

```
 //this controller delegate method 
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[tableview reloadData];
}
```

when you will pop main view it will get call

Comment: im calling reloadData in viewDidAppear in MainView

Comment: call it in viewwillappear in mainview controller class and put breakpoint check wether this method get call or not

Comment: and update array that you are using in count  for no of row in viewwillappear then  call reloadData